# The James Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let us define $\tilde{J}$ to be the space of all sequences $\xi=(\xi(n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers with finite square variation; that is, $\xi\in\tilde{J} $ if and only if there is a constant M such that for every choice of integers $((p)_{j})_{j=0}^{n}$ with $1\leq p_{0}<p_{1}<\dots<p_{n} $ we have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\xi(p_{j})-\xi(p_{j-1}))^{2}\leq M^{2}$$

Can someone tell why is this:
If $\xi \in \tilde{J},$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi(n)$ exists and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\xi(n)=0$?

Comment: What if $\xi(n)\equiv 1$?

Comment: Such a sequence must be Cauchy, not necessarily convergent to 0. James space is defined to be the set of all sequences of finite square variation that converge to 0.

Comment: you wanna know why $\lim_n \xi(n)$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $\xi(n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence. Then there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that
for every $n$
$$\tag{1}(\xi(k)-\xi(m))^2\geq \epsilon_0^2$$
for some $k,m\geq n$. Now, fix $N\geq 1$. Using $(1)$ recursively, we find pairs of indices $(k_j,m_j)$ for $j=1,...,N$ with the following ordering
$$k_1<m_1<k_2<m_2<...<k_N<m_N$$
and $$\tag{2}(\xi(k_j)-\xi(m_j))^2\geq \epsilon_0^2$$ for every $j=1,...,N$ (check that this can be done).Now let $$p_1=k_1,p_2=m_1,...,p_{2N-1}=k_N,p_{2N}=m_N$$
Then this choice of integers has the orderding $p_1<p_2<...<p_{2N-1}<p_{2N}$ and by $(2)$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2N-1}(\xi(p_j)-\xi(p_{j+1}))^2\geq \sum_{k=1}^{N}(\xi(k_j)-\xi(m_j))^2\geq N\epsilon_0^2$$
Since, N was arbitrary we conclude that $\xi(n)$ cant have a finite square variation.